# How to join sp to table Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Im using EF (edmx not code first) and i want to join a sp to a 'normal' table so i use the following linq query:

```
var test = (from obj1 in e.myTable
            join obj2 in e.MySp(aString) on obj1.AStringProperty equals obj2.AStringProperty
            select r.description).ToList();
```

Which then throws a NotsupportedException with the following message:

```
Unable to create a constant value of type 'Api.DataAccess.Contexts.MySp_Result'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.
```

But all the property's I'm using to join are a string so the only thing I can assume is that the fact that the generated object returned by the sp has an `int?` and a `long?` causes this error? If so how could I get around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't join with Stored procedures in SQL (linq generates SQL), use a User defined function instead.

Answer (score 0):

can You try this:

```
var test = (from obj1 in e.myTable
            from obj2 in e.MySp(aString) 
            where obj1.AStringProperty == obj2.AStringProperty
            select r.description).ToList();
```

Comment: can't see how this would help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in EF as well as in SQL. Linq-to-entities query is translated to SQL. You can't join result set from SP to any other query.

The only possible way is:

```
var test = (from obj1 in e.myTable.ToList()             
            join obj2 in e.MySp(aString) on obj1.AStringProperty equals obj2.AStringProperty             
            select r.description).ToList();
```

But it will be executed as Linq-To-Objects so the whole content of myTable will be transfered to application as well as the whole result set from MySp and join will be performed in memory.